# How to pass multiple simple text and input text to struts action class

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

I have iterated records from database mean while i have added input like radio button and text box.How to pass iterated values,radio button and text box values to action class.

**this is a sample code**

```
<s:form action="actionname" theme="css_xhtml" cssClass="form-horizontal">
        <s:iterator value="result">
        <td ><s:property value="Name" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="city" /></td>
       <td><input type="radio" name="rb" value="1"> /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt" > /></td>
        </s:iterator>
<s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
</s:form>
```

form this i got values in my jsp as

[image: This is a jsp page i got after iteration]

Comment: To pass simple text, use an input type hidden (<s:hidden>). To pass objects to a list, use the iteratorstatus to specify an index.

Comment: Also looks like your not using the values in `result` what type of array is it? If it is an object array you can use `<s:property value="propertyName" />` as the `value`

Comment: ya its object only but my problem is not with iterator.My problem is i have got the values from iterator as i shown (This is a jsp page i got after iteration) in this link.here i have to send all details to my struts action class details like Name,City, radiobutton and text box values and thanks for ur comments

Comment: Use List or array.

Comment: How can i check radio button is clicked or not for particular user

Comment: can u show me how to do in answer section and thanks for ur comment

Comment: there's a problem with the image, it has not all values

Comment: which values you  want in `ActionClass` ?

Comment: i want all the values eg: name,city,radiobutton and text values

Comment: how can i send values in row as 1object

Comment: How can i send values in row as object  for example here row1 values like name,city radiobutton,text values as 1 object and row2 values like name,city radiobutton,text values as another object to my action class

Comment: Make  one `POJO(Plain Old Java Object)` class, write all **4 properties** in it, And make its `List` in your action as `Member variable with getters and setters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jsp**

```
<s:form action="actionname" theme="css_xhtml" cssClass="form-horizontal">
         <s:iterator value="result">
      <td><s:hidden name="Name"value="%{Name}"/>
         <s:property value="Name" /></td>
      <td><s:hidden name="city"value="%{city}" />
          <s:property value="city" /></td>
      <td><<s:checkbox name="rb" fieldValue="check"/></td>                                  
      <td><s:textfield name="txt"cssClass="form-control" /></td>
            </s:iterator>
    <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
    </s:form>
```

**Configuration**

```
<struts>
        <package name="yourPackageName"  extends="struts-default" >
        <action name="youActionName" class="qualified class path">
        <!-- result declaration-->                      
        </action>       
    </package>  
</struts>
```

**Action class**

```
 public class YourActionClass extends ActionSupport {

    String [] rb=null;
    String [] name=null;
    String [] city=null;
    String [] txt=null;

    public String[] getRb() {
            return rb;
        }



        public void setRb(String[] rb) {
            this.rb = rb;
        }



        public String[] getName() {
            return name;
        }



        public void setName(String[] name) {
            this.name = name;
        }



        public String[] getCity() {
            return city;
        }



        public void setCity(String[] city) {
            this.city = city;
        }



        public String[] getTxt() {
            return txt;
        }



        public void setTxt(String[] txt) {
            this.txt = txt;
        }

    public String execute() throws Exception {      


    for(int j=0;j<name.length;j++)
    {
     System.out.println(Name[j]);
                System.out.println(city[j]);
                System.out.println(rb[j]);
                System.out.println(txt[j]);

    }

            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my jsp code

```
<s:form action="actionname" theme="css_xhtml" cssClass="form-horizontal">
         <s:iterator value="result">
      <td><s:hidden name="Name"value="%{Name}"/>
         <s:property value="Name" /></td>
      <td><s:hidden name="city"value="%{city}" />
          <s:property value="city" /></td>
      <td><<s:checkbox name="rb" fieldValue="check"/></td>                                  
      <td><s:textfield name="txt"cssClass="form-control" /></td>
            </s:iterator>
    <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
    </s:form>
```

in my action class  i used string array

```
String[] rb;
String[] Name;
String[] city;
String[] txt;
```

then i iterated using for loop to get each value

```
for (int i = 0; i < Name.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Name[i]);
            System.out.println(city[i]);
            System.out.println(rb[i]);
            System.out.println(txt[i]);

        }
```